# Elasticsearch date format parsing error

Tags: date, elasticsearch, elasticsearch-mapping

I am trying to specify a date format for an Elasticsearch field according to ISO 8601 as:

`YYYY-MM-DDThh:mm:ssTZD`

I put the field mapping like so:

```
"properties": {
                        "startDate": {
                            "type": "date",
                            "format": "YYYY-MM-DD'T'hh:mm:ss'TZD'"
                        }
              }
```

When I try to insert a document with this field's value as: `"startDate": "2018-01-10T07:07:07+01:00"`, I get this error:

```
"type": "mapper_parsing_exception",
        "reason": "failed to parse [afield.startDate]",
        "caused_by": {
            "type": "illegal_argument_exception",
            "reason": "Invalid format: \"2018-01-10T07:07:07+01:00\" is malformed at \"+01:00\""
        }
```

Is there something wrong in the date I am inserting? I'm following the example given in this W3C guide (https://www.w3.org/TR/NOTE-datetime):

```
Complete date plus hours, minutes and seconds:

YYYY-MM-DDThh:mm:ssTZD (eg 1997-07-16T19:20:30+01:00)
```

Comment: Was any of the answers helpful? :)

Answer (score 2):

Elasticsearch datetime formats can be found here: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/mapping-date-format.html

You want a datetime with no milliseconds. To do that, use the following:

```
 PUT my_index
 {
     "settings" : {
         "number_of_shards" : 1
     },
     "mappings" : {
         "type1" : {
           "properties": {
               "startDate": {
                   "type": "basic_date_time_no_millis",
                        "format": "yyyyMMdd'T'HHmmssZ"
                            }
                         }
                     }    
                  }
     }
```

Timezone should be handled in the timestamp, and can be pulled from a query like:

```
 GET /my_index/_search
 {
     "query": {
         "range" : {
             "timestamp" : {
                 "gte": "2018-01-10 07:07:07", 
                 "lte": "now", 
                 "time_zone": "+01:00"
             }
         }
     }
 }
```

Comment: Not sure if that works because that format doesn't use hyphens. Also, having to specify each time `time_zone` doesn't look very convenient in this case.

Comment: This is what is suggested as best practice from documentation. I agree, it does seem weird but it does work, I tried it prior to posting.

Answer (score 2):

For custom date formats in Elasticsearch you have to check the [Joda-time documentation](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/apidocs/org/joda/time/format/DateTimeFormat.html).

In your case you can try with `yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssZ`:

```
"properties": {
  "startDate": {
    "type": "date",
    "format": "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssZ"
  }
}
```

With this you should be able to insert dates and make searches using the dates like the one you used in your example: `2018-01-10T07:07:07+01:00`.

Answer (score 0):

For all the people out there that have a date in the format :

`2016-08-14T00:00:00+02:00`

or :

`yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ss+HH:MM`

You might consider using this format in elasticsearch :

`format: "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss+02:00"`